# How do i convert char to string in java and use it after for loop? (Java)

Tags: java

```
public class SezarKriptolojisi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String deneme = "Sezar Algorithm";

        for (int i = 0; i < deneme.length(); i++) {
            if (deneme.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            int sayi = deneme.codePointAt(i) + 3;
            char c = (char) sayi;
        }
        String sezar = Character.toString(c); // Error here
        System.out.print(sezar);
    }
}
```

I can't use my string out of for loop. How do i make it permanent?

I get the error "c cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: String.valueOf('x');

Answer (score 0):

declare it before the loop starts

```
public class SezarKriptolojisi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String deneme="Sezar Algorithm";

        // this
        char c = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < deneme.length(); i++) {
            if (deneme.charAt(i)==' ') {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            int sayi=deneme.codePointAt(i)+3;
            c = (char) sayi;    
        }
        String sezar= Character.toString(c);
        System.out.print(sezar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have declared c as local variable with in the for loop. Declaring c out side the loop before loop starts will resolve the issue I think.